# Can any one tell me how to remove this Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/restlet/Restlet

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.restlet.Restlet

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Could not find the main class: ucsRestService.service.UCSRestService. Program will exit.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load a class that was available at compile time, but is not available at runtime.  Ensure that the jar containing `org.restlet.Restlet` is available on your classpath.

org.restlet.jar maybe.

Comment: can you please tell me how to create jar file of a Hibernate project in Eclispe

Comment: file export (select jar)

Comment: user2310289 - In netbeans,right click on the project and select the option clean and build ,your jar file will be saved in the dist folder

Answer (score 0):

It is a jar file. Download it from here http://maven.restlet.org/.
Then import it in your project.

Comment: I have already included in the project but still I am getting this Exception